# Composite function. Textbook answer incorrect?

Tags: calculus, functions, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I am practicing composite functions and I can't get the same answer as the back of the textbook but I am confident in my calculations which leads me to believe the book is wrong.

**Question**

Let *a* be a positive number, $f:[2,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=a-x $ and let $g:(-\infty,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, g(x)=x^2+a$. Find all values of $a$ for which both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ exist.

---

**My attempt**

I know for $g\circ f$, $Ran$  $f$ must be a subset of $dom$ $g$ and for $f\circ g$, $Ran$  $g$ must be a subset of $dom$ $f$ therefore:

$dom$ $g= (-\infty,1]$ and $Ran$ $f=(-\infty, a-2]$

$dom$ $f= [2,\infty)$ and $Ran$ $g=[1+a,\infty)$

When I solve I am left with:

$a-2 \leq 1 $ and;

$1+a \geq 2 $

Therefore

$a \in [1,3]$

---

The solution in the textbook shows the answer to be $a \in [2,3]$

Can someone please help me out. Am I correct or is the textbook correct? If I have made an error can you please help me solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  When $a=1, $ the image of $g$ is $[1,\infty)$, and $f$ is not defined on all of that, so $f\circ g$ does not exist when $a=1$

Comment: did you mean dom $g=(\color{red}-\infty,1\color{red}]$?  and why did you write $1+a\ge1$ instead of $1+a\ge\color{red}2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hello J.W. Yes this is what I should have written. I have edited my original post to show this. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textbook is correct.

Your mistake is that the range of $g$ is $[a,\infty)$, because the domain of $g$ contains $0$.

(You might want to look at $g$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,1]$ separately.)

Therefore, in the second line you should have $a\ge2$ where you wrote $1+a\ge1$.

Comment: Perfect! I see the error in my calculation now. Thank you so much!!